# elastic search query to select most relevant data for given keyword

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I have  search query to get data from elastic search DB. The query is below

```
GET /v_entity_master/_search
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "(*gupta*)",
            "fields": [
              "id","name","mobile"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "*7542*",
            "fields": [
              "id","name","mobile"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This query return

```
{
"id":34501,
"name": "sree gupta",
"mobile":"98775421
},
{
"id":12302,
"name": "gupta",
"mobile":"98775422
}
```

But what I required is, the exact match of the given search key word should be in the 1st result

Expected output is ,

```
{
"id":12302,
"name": "gupta",
"mobile":"98775422
},{
"id":34501,
"name": "sree gupta",
"mobile":"98775421
}
```

Please share your suggestion and idea to slove this issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: have you had any success with my answer? If yes, I would really appreciate accepting my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So first of all, why would you search for **"(*gupta*)"** in the id and mobile (phone?) field? Based on the two results you shared, they are numeric fields so whats your intention with that?

Same issue with the second must-clause. I've never encountered a real name of a human being that includes numeric values...

I also don't get why you use the wildcards in the first must-clause. I assume you want to do a fulltext search. So you can simply use the [match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html).

Now to your actual question:

I created an index in my test cluster and indexed the two responses you showed as documents. This is the response when I execute **your** query:

```
{
  ...
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 2.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "gupta",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 2.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 12302,
          "name" : "gupta",
          "mobile" : "98775422"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "gupta",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 2.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 34501,
          "name" : "sree gupta",
          "mobile" : "98775421"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Notice that **both** documents have the same score. That's because you specified wildcards in your search query.

Now let's modify your query:

```
GET gupta/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "name": "gupta"
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "*7542*",
            "fields": ["mobile"]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The main difference is that this query uses a match query to do that fulltext search. You don't need to specify any wildcards since your text fields are analyzed.

This will return the following:

```
{
  ...
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.2111092,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "gupta",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.2111092,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 12302,
          "name" : "gupta",
          "mobile" : "98775422"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "gupta",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 1.160443,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 34501,
          "name" : "sree gupta",
          "mobile" : "98775421"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Now the two documents have different scores due to **Field length normalization**. As stated in this [article about elasticsearch scoring](https://www.compose.com/articles/how-scoring-works-in-elasticsearch/) *a term match found in a field with a low number of total terms is going to be more important than a match found in a field with a large number of terms.*

I hope I could help you.